# dynamic Import for multiple functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, dynamic-import

I have a static import like below in in my code

```
import { findBotletByTelephonyNumber, fetchClientCustomSettings, fetchCallerStatus } from './../shared/custom-settings.service';
```

which are developed like below

```
export const findBotletByTelephonyNumber = (x) => { //return something }
```

and I am using them in another function.

Now I want to switch to `dynamic import` (Typescript), all examples on the net are importing a single module.

My question is how can I import multiple functions (one by one or all together) with dynamic import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, in case somebody else has same issue

```
const customSettingsModule = await import('./../shared/custom-settings.service');

customSettingsModule.findBotletByTelephonyNumber(6);
```